# Windows Phone 8 Profiling tool "Analysis of log file failed"

Tags: windows-phone-8, profiling

I start the Windows Phone Application Analysis tool (Alt+F1) and try monitoring or profiling execution of my Monogame Windows Phone 8 game for just a few seconds and then I end the session.
Copying and parsing log file go fine, but the analysis of log fails.

This used to work in a very old version of my game, and it works on any sample project I download from internet.

Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: Did you upgrade your app from WP7.1 ? - If so, check and compare the .csproj. I had a similar issue longer time ago.

Comment: No. I started a new project from the Monogame Template.

Answer (score 0):

in your Windows %TEMP% directory a file is created (usually named ProfilerLog_appname_xxxxxxxxx.txt ) which shows the error of the profiler parsing.

Being a MonoGame user too, I haven't been able to profile my apps for a long time (tried VS2010, VS2012 and VS2013 so far).

EDIT: If you can, converting your game to Universal App will allow you to profile your code using the "Performance and Diagnosis" option (Alt+F2). If you're looking for bottlenecks, you can profile it as a WP8.1 and then port the changes back to WP8.0